# Spaces being removed when posting data from ASPX to ASP page, but spaces preserved when posting to ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, urlencode, webrequest

Spaces being removed when posting data from ASPX to ASP page, but spaces preserved when posting data to ASPX page. Below is the sample code

> calling program code (aspx code behind)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/asppost/asppost.asp");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "LastName=Ahamed&Addr1=100 Main Street";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// Display the status.
Debug.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Display the content.
Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

> asppost.asp

```
<%
Dim Lname, AddressLine1
Lname = Request.Form("LastName")
AddressLine1 = Request.Form("AddressLine1")
Response.Write("Last Name: " & Lname)
Response.Write(" Address Line1: " & AddressLine1)
%>
```

> output

```
OK
Last Name: Ahamed Address Line1: 100MainStreet
```

Problem will be solved if I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode as below, but my question is why and how spaces are preserved when posting the same data (without UrlEncode) to ASPX page?

```
string postData = "LastName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Ahamed") + "&AddressLine1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("100 Main Street");
```

Please share your ideas.

Comment: It might be happening automatically as part of your URL rewrite in asp.net?

Comment: @safetyOtter, No URL rewrite rule in my asp.net app. Anything else do you think of?

Answer (score 0):

The data in your postData string needs to be URL Encoded.

This    `postData = "LastName=Ahamed&Addr1=100 Main Street";`

needs to be:  `postData = "LastName=Ahamed&Addr1=100+Main+Street";`

In code this will be something like:

```
string postData = "LastName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lastName);
postData += "&Addr1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(addr1);
```